# calling fragment and passing parameters

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a fragment with this initializing:

```
    public static final PageFragment newInstance(int id,long stage_count){
    PageFragment fragment=new PageFragment();
    final Bundle args = new Bundle(2);
    args.putInt("EXTRA_ID", id);
    args.putLong("EXTRA_COUNT", stage_count);
    fragment.setArguments(args);

    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.id = getArguments().getInt("EXTRA_ID");
    this.stage_count = getArguments().getLong("EXTRA_COUNT");
}
```

my problem is how i can call it? for example i want to instantiate this fragment and pass that two parameters. in regular way i does this:

```
PageFragment fragment=new PageFragment(1,1);
```

But now how i can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually,if you extend Fragment and declare any constructor ,you will be given a warning 
because when the system restores a fragment (e.g on config change), it will automatically restore your bundle.
From your aspect,it is ok to pass parameters in constructor .

However if a fragment is instanced in constructor with paramerers, thoese wont be restored

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
PageFragment fragment = PageFragment.newInstance(1,1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The common pattern is to create a static method named `newInstance()` inside your fragment subclass. This acts as the constructor and encapsulates creating the arguments `Bundle` and calling `setArguments()`.

You cannot pass the arguments through a regular constructor because of the design.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you.

```
Pagefragment pageFragment = PageFragment.newInstance(value1, value2);
```